# Cordova Facebook Plugin FB.ui does nothing iOS

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the Facebook sdk 3.2 with cordova 2.8.1 and the officia phonegap facebook plugin 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

I am able to get the login flow working perfectly, but anytime I try to write any code with dialogs nothing happens (no errors in either the console or output on Xcode.  For example the below code.  The alerts are never called nor is the console.log.

```
FB.ui({  
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
        link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
        picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
        caption: 'Reference Documentation',
        description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
            },
            function(response) {
                console.log("in callback");
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                    alert('Post was published.');
                } else {
                    alert('Post was not published.');
                }
            }
         );
```

Additionally I have tested the sample code and have the same issues there.  Looking through cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js I do not see anything to handle the FB.ui function in the javascript.  Any help here.

I have yet to try on android.